# How to add text input to python ai

Tags: python, input

I've created a python ai, and sometimes it cant understand me because of my accent/lisp & when it cant understand me i want to manually type in the command. How do i do this? I want to allow keyboard input as a source for commands (I just want to be able to type in my commands).

Code is below:

```
# H.I.V.E V.0.0.3 BETA: Home-Assistant Integrated Virtual Environment
# #VIEW THE HIVE PROJECT AT HTTPS://natebrownprojects.github.io/TheHiveProject/
# Copyright: Nate Brown Projects 2021 / Nate Brown 2021 / TheHiveProjectNZ 2021
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import wikipedia
import pyjokes
from pyttsx3 import Engine

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine: Engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0]  .id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
talk('Systems Loading, Welcome to the HIVE.')
talk('How, can i help, you Sir?')

def take_command():
    try:

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'hive' in command:
                command = command.replace('hive', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_hive():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'date' in command:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        talk("Current date and time : ")
        talk(now.strftime("%d         %m                %Y"))
        engine.setProperty("rate", 178)
    elif 'who is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1, auto_suggest=False)

        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    elif 'status report' in command:
        talk('All Systems Operational Sir!')
    elif 'hive' in command:
        talk('Yes, sir?')
    elif 'shut down' in command:
        talk('Shutting all Hive Systems Down.')
        talk('Thank you for using hive! Goodbye!')
        print('Thank you for using H.I.V.E!')
        exit()

    elif 'exit' in command:
        talk('Shutting all Hive Systems Down.')
        talk('Thank you for using hive! Goodbye!')
        print('Thank you for using H.I.V.E!')
        exit()
    elif 'awesome thanks' in command:
        talk('Your, Welcome!')
    elif 'thanks' in command:
        talk('Ny Pleasure!')
    elif 'thank you' in command:
        talk('No Problem!')
    elif 'awesome' in command:
        talk('No Problem, is there anything i, can help you, with?')
    elif ' no' in command:
         talk('ok!')
    elif 'yes' in command:
        talk('Ok, what is it?')
    elif 'how are you' in command:
        talk('Im Great, How are you!?')
    elif 'you still there' in command:
        talk('Yes Sir, i am ready for your command!')
    elif 'who are you' in command:
        talk('My name is Hive. It stands for Home Assistant Integrated Virtual Environment. I am here to help you with whatever i can')
    elif 'hello' in command:
        talk('hello, how are you today?')

    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    try:
        run_hive()
    except UnboundLocalError:

        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the take_command function a little, such as:

```
def take_command():
    # ask the user if he wants to use the mike
    opt = input('use the mike(y/n)?: ')
    # if not, he would type his command
    if opt.lower() == "n":
        return input("Please type your command: ").lower()
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'hive' in command:
                command = command.replace('hive', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe controlling the input form with a boolean value, I tried to not change any code or function calls. Just to leave it as you want it, but with the implementation of a boolean that is checked either if you want a keyboard input or just your voice giving the commands.

Code Snippet:

```
KeyboardInterrupt = False


def take_command():
    choice = input("Keyboard input?")
    if(choice=="Yes" or choice=="yes"):
        KeyboardInterrupt = True
    else:
        KeyboardInterrupt = False
    try:
        if not KeyboardInterrupt:
        
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                voice = listener.listen(source)
                command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
                command = command.lower()
                if 'hive' in command:
                    command = command.replace('hive', '')
                    print(command)
        else:
            command = input("Type your command: ")            
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be on the right track but im getting the following error:

```Keyboard input?yes
Type your command: hello
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/natebrown/Documents/The H.I.V.E Project/script1.py", line 123, in <module>
    run_hive()
  File "/Users/natebrown/Documents/The H.I.V.E Project/script1.py", line 51, in run_hive
    if 'play' in command:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1 ```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet you edited? I would like to help if I can!

Comment: I just tried the code and got no error message at all. In your function (def talk(text)) I placed a print statement because I didn't load all the dependencies. But it worked all fine:    def talk(text): print(text)